# Firebase CLI delete vs Rest API update with null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

Goal here to delete as fast as possible keeping Firebaes Realtime Database instance utilization under 100 %.

I have 360 GB data in Firebase Realtime Database. Now I want to delete most the data that is not need. I have script that is doing delete by using firebase database:remove /node1/child1 (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/large-deletes-in-realtime-database.html)

Node Structure

```
"node1":{
   "child1":{
    "thousand of child's node here i want to delete"
    }, 
    "child2":{
    "thousand of child's node here i want to delete"
    },
   "child3":{
    "child3 is required can not delete this one "
    }
}
```

I was thinking if I update  path firebase database:remove /node1/child1 to null. Will it remove all the child of child 1? and difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `firebase database:remove`, as detailed in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/large-deletes-in-realtime-database.html). By just calling `remove()` or `update(null)`, you will lock the database until all data is deleted, something that could be many minutes or even hours with a dataset that large.

The CLI command will instead chunk and batch deletes into reasonable sizes, keeping your database utilization from being completely locked. In fact, with `database:remove` you don't need to manually batch -- you can just pass it the largest node that you need deleted and it will automatically take care of batching for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass null value to a firebase path, then it should be the same as remove that path.

> Passing null for the new value is equivalent to calling remove(); namely, all data at this location and all child locations will be deleted.

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set)

The implementation of remove method in firebase admin (for android) also using this set to null.

```
   /**
   * Set the value at this location to 'null'
   *
   * @return The ApiFuture for this operation.
   */
  public ApiFuture<Void> removeValueAsync() {
    return setValueAsync(null);
  }
```

[Firebase source code in Java](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.java)